# How do I disable a <div> in a @media query

Tags: php, html, css

I made a Binary-Calculator site where I wanted the calc to be in a gray background, but the body was supposed to be black. So i made a black Body and a Div across all the elements i wanted do be in this gray background. Everything works fine on desktop but now where i started optimizing for mobile, i realized i have to "disable" the div which causes the gray background so have a clean black ui without that gray big background line. When i test my @media query on chromes simulated phone everything is positioned right and even the div background disappears. although when I test it on my phone it looks like in the pic. Thank you in advance.

[simulated phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syMKP.png)

[Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXKPv.jpg)

[Desktop 1920x1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ7Yn.png)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@600&display=swap');

/*Desktop*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 2560px) {
body{
    background-color:black;
}

h1{
    font-family:Sans-serif; 
    font-size:60px; 
    text-decoration: underline black;
}
.background-box{
    height:100vh; 
    width:60vw;
    background-color: rgb(42, 42, 42);
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.Dezi{
    width:500px;
    height:40px;
    font-size:25px;
}

.rechnen{
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    height:70px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:white;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:black;
    border:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 white;
    transition:ease-out 0.8s;
}

.rechnen:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    box-shadow:inset 700px 0 0 0 #000000;
    color:white;
    border-color:white;
}

#operator{
    position:relative;
    top:30px;
    left:290px
}

.result{
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:25px;
}

.homebutton{
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:22px;
    width:350px;
    height:70px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    color:black;
    transition: ease-out 0.4s;
    background-color:white;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow:black;
    border-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    top:-935px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 0 white;
    border:solid;
    
}

.homebutton:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    box-shadow:inset 350px 0 0 0 black;
    color:white;
    border-color:white;
    border-width:2px;
}

.DzBR{
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:22px;
    width:350px;
    height:70px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    color:black;
    transition: ease-out 0.4s;
    background-color:white;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow:black;
    border-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    top:-870px;
    left:350px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 0 white;
    border:solid;
}

.DzBR:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    box-shadow:inset 350px 0 0 0 black;
    color:white;
    border-color:white;
    border-width:2px;
}
}

/*MOBILE*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {

    body{
        all:unset;
        background-color:white;
        text-align:center;

    }   

    h1{
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; 
        font-size:60px; 
        text-decoration: underline black;
    }

    .background-box{
        background-color: unset;
        background-color: white;
    }
    
    
    .Dezi{
        width:500px;
        height:40px;
        font-size:25px;
    }
    
    .rechnen{
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-size:20px;
        height:70px;
        width:400px;
        background-color:white;
        border-width:2px;
        border-color:black;
        border:solid;
        border-width:2px;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 white;
        transition:ease-out 0.8s;
    }
    
    .rechnen:hover{
        cursor:pointer;
        box-shadow:inset 700px 0 0 0 #000000;
        color:white;
        border-color:white;
    }
    
    #operator{
        
    }
    
    .result{
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-size:25px;
    }
    
    .homebutton{
        all:unset;
        all:revert;
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-size:22px;
        width:350px;
        height:70px;
        letter-spacing:2px;
        color:black;
        transition: ease-out 0.4s;
        background-color:white;
        float:;
        position:relative;
        box-shadow:black;
        border-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
        top:;
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 0 white;
        border:solid;
        
    }
    
    .homebutton:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
        box-shadow:inset 350px 0 0 0 black;
        color:white;
        border-color:white;
        border-width:2px;
    }
    
    .DzBR{
        all:unset;
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-size:22px;
        width:350px;
        height:70px;
        letter-spacing:2px;
        color:black;
        transition: ease-out 0.4s;
        background-color:white;
        float:;
        position:relative;
        box-shadow:black;
        border-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
        top:;
        left:;
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 0 white;
        border:solid;
    }
    
    .DzBR:hover{
        cursor:pointer;
        box-shadow:inset 350px 0 0 0 black;
        color:white;
        border-color:white;
        border-width:2px;
    }


}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="DzBRstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Dezimal zu Binär Rechner</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<div class="background-box">

<body>

<h1>Dezimal zu Binär Rechner</h1>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>



<form action="DzBR.php" method="post">

    <select id="operator" name="operator">
        <option>Dual</option>
        <option>Oktal</option>
        <option>Hexal</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    
    <input class="Dezi" name="Dezi" type="number">
    
    <br>
    <br>
    
    <button name="rechnen" class="rechnen">Rechnen</button>
</form>
</div>

<form action="../hub.php">
<button class="homebutton">Home</button>
</form>

<form action="../Binaer-Dezimal/kayedrechner.php">
<button class="DzBR">Binär zu Dezimal Rechner</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just set `display:none`  for that particular div at the media query section.

Comment: Is it OK to have that <div> before the <body>? That stands out as something that might produce unexpected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put that `background-box` div *into*  the `body` (not before it) and close it properly (with a `</div>` tag), then apply `display: none;` to it where needed (i.e. in a media query).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `display:none;` in css to "disable" a div, but will also make everything in the div invisible.

Another way is `visibility: hidden;` which make the div invisible, but it still take up space on the website

Answer (score -1):

Set the @media in this way.

```
/* start with common css for desktop and smartphone */
....

/* high resolution (only desktop) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 850px) and (max-width: 2560px) {
  ....
}

/* low resolution (only smartphone) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 849.98px) {
  ....
}
```

Using (max-width: 2560px) is not future-proof for the very hi-resolution screens.

Any `div` can be removed out of the flow with `display: none;` . Note that everything in it will also not shown.